# Error while trying to decrypt using Fernet

Tags: python, encryption, fernet

After creating a simple python encryption code with fernet library (that worked great)
I tried to code a decryptor but unfortunately while trying to use my decryptor i got the following error

```
['blahblahblah.txt', 'blah.txt']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/stuff/projects/voldemort/decrypt.py", line 24, in <module>
    contents_decrypted = Fernet(secretkey).decrypt(contents)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 34, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.
```

The Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

#find some files
files = []

#Starting the file in a loop
for file in os.listdir():
        if file == "voldemort.py" or file == "thekey.key" or file == "decrypt.py":
                continue
        if os.path.isfile(file):
                files.append(file)

print(files)

with open("thekey.key", "rb") as key:
        secretkey = key.read()

for file in files:
        with open(file, "rb") as thefile:
                contents = thefile.read()
        contents_decrypted = Fernet(secretkey).decrypt(contents)
        with open(file, "wb") as thefile:
                thefile.write(contents_decrypted)
```

Comment: Please *update the question* to include the value of `secretkey`.

Comment: The problem is the content of `thekey.key` isn't saved correctly, but that code isn't shown.

Answer (score 1):

The error simply states the key used is invalid. `Fernet` is expecting a (url-safe) 32-byte base64 encoded string, as the key.

There are *many* methods for generating such a string, here are two simpler examples:

#### Option 1:

Let `Fernet` do it for you:

```
from cryptography import fernet

key = fernet.Fernet.generate_key()
```

Output:

```
b'd25vYTghWVgkTQWrMFnwW1tfKtn_lWzDr2JJM95f2fs='
```

#### Option 2:

Create one yourself using a (unique) randomly generated UUID4 string:

```
import base64
import uuid

key = base64.b64encode(uuid.uuid4().hex.encode())
```

Output:

```
b'M2E4MmQ2MDJlNmZmNDQwN2I3Y2NiN2I0ZDJkMzA4Zjk='
```

---

Addressing the helpful comment about writing the key to a file, one can use:

```
with open('keyfile.key', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(key)
```

Remember, `Fernet` is looking for a *bytestring*, so it's important to store the file using the `'wb'` (write binary) mode.

Comment: And then, save it correctly to `thekey.key` by writing as `with open('thekey.key','wb') as f: f.write(key)`, which is probably the real root cause.  My guess is the OP used something like `with open('thekey.key','w') as f: f.write(str(key))` instead of binary mode, but that code isn't shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is your Fernet key is not encoded correctly.

*UPDATED TO SUPPORT RAW FILE OUTPUT

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import hashlib
import zlib, base64, json

SALT = 'secretpassword'        

def cryptkey(password=''):
    digest = hashes.Hash(hashes.SHA256(), backend=default_backend())
    digest.update(SALT+password)
    return Fernet(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(digest.finalize()))

def encrypt(meta, password=''):
    meta = str(zlib.compress(meta, 9))
    f = cryptkey(password)
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(f.encrypt(bytes(meta)))

def decrypt(meta, password=''):
    meta = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(meta)
    f = cryptkey(password)
    meta = f.decrypt(bytes(meta))
    return zlib.decompress(meta)
```

Comment: In case of my original code that i posted above what is your recommedndation ?

Comment: While it may work (have not tested) 1) This is mass overkill for the OP’s simple error message, and 2) in no way addresses the OP’s error.

Comment: @S3DEV how does this not solve the problem?  And there was no code in the OP to solve at the time of my post so exactly how am I to know what to solve?

Comment: Perhaps an answer shouldn’t be posted if we’re not sure what we’re trying to answer.  (?)

Comment: @Lorenzo I would just use this as a module and call encrypt/decrypt with the password.  (make your own secret salt).  There really is no simpler way to do this, and this is sha256 encryption.